# Custom iOS unlock text

Tags: ios

I was on my iPhone and I got an alert from tap tap revenge. I noticed that the text was  "slide to get it now!"[image: unlock image]
Was this always apart of the SDK and how could program my app so that when a notification came up then it would have custom text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont know about push notifications, but local notifications have a property for this. alertAction, just change that string and it will change it. So if you write `notification. alertAction = @"receive";`, then the slider will say "slide to receive", or if its a alert on the device, the button to open your app will say "receive".

See the `UILocalNotification` [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/alertAction).

Answer (score 0):

**For push notifications:**

I'm can't try it right now but try to use this:

```
“alert” : { “action-loc-key” : “your text”, “body” : “your text” }
```

Refer to [this link](http://jamesjennin.gs/post/752054709/slide-to-unlock-view)